# How to combine two sql queries in the same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

When using the JSON_CONTAINS method, I cannot fetch category_id information with JOIN. How can I convert it into a single query?
thanks.

DB

```
categories
categories_id   categories_title    categories_parent_id (JSON)     categories_sef_url
1               a                   {"top": "0"}                    a
2               b                   {"top": "0"}                    b
3               c                   {"top": "0"}                    c
4               aa                  {"id": ["1"], "top": "1"}       aa
5               bb                  {"id": ["2"], "top": "2"}       bb
6               cc                  {"id": ["3"], "top": "3"}       cc
7               aaa                 {"id": ["1", "4"], "top": "4"}  aaa
8               bbb                 {"id": ["2", "5"], "top": "5"}  bbb
9               ccc                 {"id": ["3", "6"], "top": "6"}  ccc
```

SQL

```
$categories_id = 0;
$sql = "SELECT categories_id from categories where categories_sef_url='aa' ";
$data = $query = $conn->query($sql, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if (!empty($data)) {
    foreach($data as $row) {
        $categories_id = $row->categories_id;
        break;
    }
}   
$sql = "SELECT categories_id, categories_title from categories where **JSON_CONTAINS(categories_parent_id, '{\"id\":\"".$categories_id."\"}')** OR categories_id='".$categories_id."'";
$data = $query = $conn->query($sql, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if (!empty($data)) {
    foreach($data as $row) {
        echo $row->categories_id;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $row->categories_title;
        echo "<hr>";
    }
}
```

RESULT

```
4
aa
7
aaa
```

Comment: This is a poorly designed table. You don't want to store a JSON that hold some relation logic. Time to think about DB normalization

Comment: I can create more than one subcategory.
If there are other categories below the subcategory, I can find them in a single query.
I wanted to use Json with this logic.

Comment: What is the version of MySQL you are using?

Comment: MySQL 5.7.23
But because the project is not completed, the localhost.

Comment: If the value is found, JSON_CONTAINS() returns 1, otherwise it returns 0, What will your query look like for static data?

Comment: "SELECT c1.categories_id as cid1, c2.categories_id as cid2 from categories as c1 INNER JOIN categories as c2 ON c1.categories_sef_url='aa' AND JSON_CONTAINS(C2.categories_parent_id, '{\"id\":\"4\"}')";

Comment: it works this way, but it needs to be entered in a static category id.

Comment: I could not transfer the category id from c1 to JSON_CONTAINS.